# Cellular automaton in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code of the famous game of life in C++. Here is what I've got so far. when I run it, it gives an initial random population of cells, but the next generations don't seem to work. What is wrong with my code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    //Number of rows and columns   
    const char live = '*';
    const char dead = ' ';
    const int rows = 10;
    const int cols = 10;
    char life[rows][cols];
    char life1[rows][cols];

    int ans=0;


    //create initial generation randomly

    srand (time(NULL));
    int cell;


    for(int r=0; r<rows; r++){

        for(int c=0; c<cols; c++){

            cell= rand()%10;
            if(cell >= 5){
                life[r][c] = live;
                }
            else {
                life[r][c] = dead;
            } 

        }
    }


    for(int r=0; r < rows; r++){
        for(int c = 0; c<cols;c++){
            cout << life[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    for(int k=0; k <10;k++){
        for(int r=0; r < rows; r++){
            for(int c=0;c<cols;c++){
                if(life[r][c] == live){
                    if((c-1) >=1 && (life[r][c-1] == live))
                        ans++;
                    if(c<cols && (life[r][c+1] == live))
                        ans++;
                    if(c<cols && r<rows && (life[r+1][c+1] == live))
                        ans++;
                    if(r<rows && (life[r+1][c] == live))
                        ans++;
                    if(c<cols && c >=0 && (life[r+1][c-1] == live))
                        ans++;
                    if(r>=0 && c >=0 && (life[r-1][c-1] == live))
                        ans++;
                    if(r>=0 && (life[r-1][c]==live))
                        ans++;
                    if(r>=0 && c<cols && (life[r-1][c+1] == live))
                        ans++;
                    if(ans==2 || ans==3)
                        life[r][c]= live;
                    if(ans>3)
                        life[r][c]= dead;
                    if(ans<2)
                        life[r][c]=live;

                }
                else {
                    if( life[r][c]==dead){
                        if(c>=0 && (life[r][c-1]==dead))
                            ans++;
                        if(c<cols && (life[r][c+1]==dead))
                            ans++;
                        if(r<rows && c<cols && (life[r+1][c+1]==dead))
                            ans++;
                        if(r<rows && (life[r][c]==life[r+1][c]))
                            ans++;
                        if(r<rows && c>0 && (life[r][c]==life[r+1][c-1]))
                            ans++;
                        if(r>=0 && c>=0 && (life[r][c]==life[r-1][c-1]))
                            ans++;
                        if(r>=0 &&(life[r][c]==life[r-1][c]))
                            ans++;
                        if(r>=0 && c<cols && (life[r][c] == life[r-1][c+1]))
                            ans++;
                        if(ans==3)
                            life[r][c]=live;

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(int r=0; r<rows; r++){
            for(int c=0; c< cols; c++){
                life[r][c]=life1[r][c];
            }
        }

        for(int r=0; r<rows;r++){
            for(int c =0; c<cols;c++){
                cout << life[r][c] << " ";

            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not alternating between `life` and `life1` in your iterations, so the calculation base will be changed as soon as the first cell was re-computed. Also, from the algorithm point of view, `if(ans<2) life[r][c]=live;` looks wrong

Comment: it should be life1[r][c]=live; correct?

Comment: Generally, you need to assign the results to `life1` in the inner loops. But as far as my understanding goes, the specific point of code should be more like `if(ans<2) life[r][c] = dead;`, NOT `live`.

Comment: your implementation is not really C++. The only features of C++ you are using is cout.  if you replace those your code is simply C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets start with the minimal changes that are required to make your code work.

- Reset `ans` every iteration: At the beginning of the inner loop (over `cols`), set `ans = 0;` otherwise you count above `3`, never return and everything stays `dead`
- Keep your generation: The next generation is computed from the `life` array, so don't change this array while computing a generation. Instead write the results to `life1`. At the end of each outer (`k`) iteration, the results will be copied back to `life`.
- Apply the rules correctly: at the end of `if (life[r][c] == live)` case, with fewer than 2 neighbors, the cell should die according to the rules. So assign `if (ans < 2) life1[r][c] = dead;` instead of `live`.
- With usage of `life1`, complete the assignment: For the other case (`if (life[r][c] == dead)`) add an `else` to make sure complete initialization: `if(ans==3) life1[r][c] = live; else life1[r][c] = dead`.
- Use whole array size (starting at index `0`): `if ((c - 1) >= 1 && (life[r][c - 1] == live))` ommits the first index. Replace with `if (c >= 1 && (life[r][c - 1] == live))`
- Stay within array bounds (ending at `size-1`). `if(c < cols && (life[r][c + 1] == live))` is going out of bounds, replace with `if((c + 1) < cols && (life[r][c + 1] == live))` to stay within bounds.
- Be careful with the array bounds on all other `if` statements in the same way as described for the two examples.

Now moving on to the code design: I'd suggest you create a function `int count_living_neighbors(char life[10][10], int rowPos, int colPos)` where you place all the logic to count living neighbor cells. Then replace the huge `if` cascades in your main:

```
for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
{
    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            int count = count_living_neighbors(life, r, c);
            if(life[r][c] == live)
            {
                if(count == 2 || count == 3)
                    life1[r][c] = live;
                else
                    life1[r][c] = dead;
            }
            else
            {
                if(count == 3)
                    life1[r][c]=live;
                else
                    life1[r][c]= dead;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            life[r][c] = life1[r][c];
        }
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        {
            cout << life[r][c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

A note regarding `count_living_neighbors`: Actually it would be better to take a `char* life` and additionally the row and column size as parameters. But it makes array arithmetic a bit less obvious.

**Edit:**

Moving the constant values into global scope, the `count_living_neighbors` function could look like this:

```
const char live = '*';
const char dead = ' ';
const int rows = 10;
const int cols = 10;

int count_living_neighbors(char life[rows][cols], int r, int c)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool top = r <= 0;
    bool bottom = r >= (rows - 1);
    bool left = c <= 0;
    bool right = c >= (cols - 1);

    if (!left && life[r][c - 1] == live)
        ++count;
    if (!right && life[r][c + 1] == live)
        ++count;

    if (!top)
    {
        if (life[r - 1][c] == live)
            ++count;
        if (!left && life[r - 1][c - 1] == live)
            ++count;
        if (!right && life[r - 1][c + 1] == live)
            ++count;
    }

    if (!bottom)
    {
        if (life[r + 1][c] == live)
            ++count;
        if (!left && life[r + 1][c - 1] == live)
            ++count;
        if (!right && life[r + 1][c + 1] == live)
            ++count;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: I did the changes, but I still dont get the result. I get the first random initial population and then all is blank

Comment: Oops, just realized you never reset `ans`, so it is just increasing until everything is dead ;)

Comment: Added the `ans` reset as well as another thing: array indices to from `0` to `size-1`, but at some points you use them like `1` to `size` which is wrong.

Comment: it is working now! the problem is that all the generations after the initial one appear all at once. Is there a way to show one generation after another but with a pause of, say 2 or 3 seconds?

Comment: @ILoveMath Don't ask arbitrary off-topic extra questions - just look for "C++ sleep" in your favorite search engine / documentation source / whatever you use for educational purposes ;)

Comment: I'd go even further with additional functions, like creating one function that decides if a cell lives based on the current status and the neighbourhood count, one function that does the computation of life1, one to write life1 into life and one to print. Makes every step clearly readable. Also I'd make a class GameOfLife out of it. ILoveMath looks like a beginner and teaching a proper style might be quite beneficial. If you allow it, I will add it to your answer (don't want to edit your answer uninvited). I can also create a new answer if you'd prefer that.

Comment: @Aziuth Go ahead if you want, just keep the minimum change list alive, since I want to distinguish between "make it work" and "better design". I agree that class encapsulation and more fine grained sub-functions would improve the code. Your choice if you create a new answer or edit this one. I'd probably upvote yours ;)

Comment: I think you have a typo in line 9 of your second code. Should be r >= 0

Comment: @ILoveMath No, I'm asking the question there, whether `r` is at the top corner of the field. With `r >= 0` I would ask whether `r` is a valid index - but I don't actually check this in the function

Comment: question: this  if statement:  if(r>=0 && c<cols && (life[r-1][c+1] == live)) should be   if(r>=1 && c<cols && (life[r-1][c+1] == live)) right?

Comment: @ILoveMath Nope, it should be `if (r >= 1 && (c + 1) < cols && (life[r - 1][c + 1] == live))`

Answer (score 3):

The actual answer is already given by grek40, but I figured that it might not hurt to give you some advice on coding style. This answer is based on the code of grek40.

First of all, if you work over some structure of data, this is a clear sign that you want a class. I will also get rid of the arrays (you want to avoid those in C++) and make the state of a cell more readable by using enum.

Let's begin with an interface, situated in a header file.

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

enum CellState{ //replacing your char* with CellState
    dead, alive
};

class GameOfLife{

public:

    GameOfLife(const unsigned int rows, const unsigned int cols);
    virtual ~GameOfLife(){}; //can omit the virtual if no subclasses are guaranteed

    void iterate(const unsigned int iterations = 1); //can do several steps at once, one step at a time is the assumed default
    void print() const;

private:
    vector<vector<CellState> > state;

    void initialize(const unsigned int rows, const unsigned int cols); //does the randomization
    unsigned int neighbors(const unsigned int row, const unsigned int col) const;
}
```

This class makes your main function look very easy to read:

```
#include "GameOfLife.h"

int main(){

    GameOfLife game(10,10);
    game.print(); //print initial configuration
    game.iterate(); //or iterate(10) or how many steps you want
    game.print(); //print configuration at the end

    return 0;
}
```

Let's continue with the implementations of the class, situated in GameOfLife.cpp. I will omit the necessary includes like iostream for now.

Let's begin with the easy one, print:

```
inline char state_to_char(const CellState state){
    if(state == dead){
        return ' ';
    }
    return '*';
}

void GameOfLife::print() const{
    for(unsigned int r = 0; r < state.size(); r++){
        for(unsigned int c = 0; c < state[r].size(); c++){
            cout << state_to_char(state[r][c]) << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Now for initialize:

```
void GameOfLife::initialize(const unsigned int rows, const unsigned int cols){

    state.resize(rows);
    for(unsigned int r = 0, r < rows, r++){
        state[r].resize(cols);
    }

    insert your code of randomly assigning dead or alive with changed names
}
```

The constructor simply becomes

```
GameOfLife::GameOfLife(const unsigned int rows, const unsigned int cols){
    initialize(rows, cols);
}
```

(initialize was created to make it easier to introduce new constructors later on if required)

unsigned int neighbors is to be like grek40 designed count_living_neighbors.

For the core part, iterate:

```
//function to resize any vector^2
template<class T>
void resize(vector<vector<T> >& target, const unsigned int dx, const unsigned int dy){
    target.resize(dx);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<dx; i++){
        target[i].resize(dy);
    }
}

GameOfLife::iterate(const unsigned int iterations){

    unsigned int rows = state.size();
    unsigned int cells = 0;
    if(rows != 0){
        cells = state[0].size();
    }

    vector<vector<CellState> > new_state;
    resize(new_state, rows, cells);

    for(unsigned int iteration = 0; iteration < iterations; iteration++){

        for(unsigned int r = 0; r < rows; r++){
            for(unsigned int c = 0; c < cells; c++){

                unsigned int count = neighbors(r, c);
                if(state[r][c] == alive){
                    if(count == 2 || count == 3){
                        new_state[r][c] = alive;
                    }else{
                        new_state[r][c] = dead;
                }else{
                    if(count == 3){
                        new_state[r][c] = alive;
                    }else{
                        new_state[r][c] = dead;
                    }
                }
            }//end for c
        }//end for r

        state = new_state;

    }//end for iteration
}
```

Now, all in all, this is more code than before, but for any part of it, we know exactly what it does, can easily read it, and if there is a bug, we can easily locate the bug using a debugger.

Comment: `neighbors(life, r, c);` should be `neighbors(r, c);`. Don't write complex refactoring code in the answer editor :)

Comment: @grek40 Thanks, changed that. If you find more mistakes, feel free to edit.

Comment: Not a mistake, but having `vector<vector<CellState> > new_state = state;` inside the `iterations` loop is unnecessary recreation of new_state, since all fields will be re-initialized with the correct value during the inner loops. It could be created once outside the loops.

Comment: @grek40 K, changed that.